# как создать собственный сервер PostgreSQL на своем пк в pgAdmin 4 и подключиться к нему с другого пк

Tags: postgresql, psql

Не знаю как создать собственный сервер PostgreSQL на своем пк, так что бы можно было использовать его как сервер.
Менял файлы конфигурации postgresql.conf и ph_hba.conf, гуглил и пробовал все возможные варианты, помогите

Comment: Не в обиду. Судя по постановке вопроса, Вам в это еще рано.

Answer (score 0):

Добро пожаловать в PgSQL! )))

Во первых проверяем файл `postgresql.conf`

на предмет socket listener. Он должен быть не localhost - приемлемо имя компьютера например `vasjapc` твой IP или хотя-бы `0.0.0.0`.

Строка `#listen_addresses = 'localhost'` где по умолчанию она закоментирована и ведет на 127.0.0.1 (localhost)

Далее:

Изменяем корневой файл доступов `pg_hba.conf`. Где прописываем

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
```

Что означает следующее, к pgsql можно присоединиться с любого IP на любой порт и пароль будет передаваться в md5.

Comment: PS: а вообще postgre это база enterprise уровня. Задай себе сначало вопрос - готов ли ты к этому? Её расчет не идет на пэт-проекты или личное использование. Это огромный такой жесткий танк, который может проехать через любое говно. И требует от разработчика/сисадмина максимум полезных знаний.